# PyZmq ensure connect() after bind()

Tags: python, ipc, zeromq, pyzmq

Trying to establish some communication between two python processes , I've come to use pyzmq. Since the communication is simple enough I 'm using the Zmq.PAIR messaging pattern with a tcp socket. Basically one process binds on an address and the other one connects to the same address . However both operations happen at startup , and since I cannot control the order in which the processes start , I am often encountering the case in which 'connect()' is called before 'bind()' which leads to failing in establishing communication.

- Is there a way to know a socket is not yet ready to be connected to ?
- What are the strategies to employ in such situations in order to obtain a safe connection ?

Answer (score 0):

put some sleep before connecting. so bind will run first, and connect will continue after waiting for sometime